# How can I reset the index of the rows?

Tags: mysql, index

I would like to select and insert data from an old table to the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 LIKE test1
INSERT INTO test2 SELECT timestamp, datenum FROM test1 WHERE datenum>=23 and datenum<=1000000 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datenum=VALUES(datenum)
```

Also I have and `id` column in the test2 and test1, but I would like to start the `id` from 1. If I use the query above I'm receiving the following error

```
ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1


INSERT INTO test2 SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE datenum>=23 and datenum<=1000000 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datenum=VALUES(datenum)
```

In this case the id start from 3239.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `id` is autoincrement field, and you want this value to start with 1 in new table.  You can specify column list in your first query, so it won't fail :

```
INSERT INTO test2 (`timestamp`, datenum) 
SELECT `timestamp`, datenum 
FROM test1 WHERE datenum>=23 and datenum<=1000000
```

Comment: I don't think `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datenum=VALUES(datenum)` is necessary since test2 is an empty table. +1 for this answer, anyway !!!

Comment: @ RolandoMySQLDBA : Agree, I should have read the question carefully, not just pasted... Fixing